# How to sum up arrays to then find the minimum

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Here's my problem: I have 2 sheets in my document (lets call them Sheet 1 and Sheet 2). They contain similar stuff and both look like this (Names may differ, as well as values):

[image]

Column A, C, D and F contain times (in m:ss).
Column B and E both calculate the time-difference between NameX and NameY and add ">, < or ~ ~" depending on the actual difference (ignore the coloring).

Now here comes my problem: I want to find 3 minima (on Sheet 3).
**Minimum 1** is easy, as I can just use this function (it automatically filters out column B and E):

```
MIN('Sheet 1'!A2:F2, 'Sheet 2'!A2:F2)
```

Minimum 2 and 3 are were I struggle.

**Minimum 2:** Using the example values, I want to find the minimum of (1:01+1:02), (1:02+1:05), (1:01+1:01) and (1:01+1:02) (+ whatever times are on sheet 2). Result should be 2:02.

**Minimum 3:** Again, using the example values, I want to find the minimum of (1:01+1:02+1:03), (1:02+1:05+0:30), (1:01+1:01+1:12) and (1:01+1:02+2:02) (+ whatever times are on sheet 2). Result should be 2:37.

I am currently using this formula (for minimum 3):

```
=MIN(
IFERROR(FILTER(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA({'Sheet 1'!A2:F2}+{'Sheet 1'!A3:F3}+{'Sheet 1'!A4:F4})),
IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA({'Sheet 1'!A2:F2}+{'Sheet 1'!A3:F3}+{'Sheet 1'!A4:F4}))<>0)),
IFERROR(FILTER(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA({'Sheet 2'!A2:F2}+{'Sheet 2'!A3:F3}+{'Sheet 2'!A4:F4})),
IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA({'Sheet 2'!A2:F2}+{'Sheet 2'!A3:F3}+{'Sheet 2'!A4:F4}))<>0))
)
```

Some notes: The inner IFERROR-function is needed to filter out errors that obviously occur when trying to add up column B and E. FILTER-function filters out columns that are empty (there's none in this example). The second IFERROR-function filters out FILTER-functions that return an error when they get no input at all (all columns in a sheet are empty). I want to filter of these since I don't want to get 0:00 as result

My problem is this: In my actual sheet I have 11 sheets with 16 rows to add up, but I don't want to use the formula above and create an insane monster of a formula that would x-times as long as the formula above.

So my question is: Is there an easier way to solve this problem for mimimum 3 (and therefore 4, 5, 6 ...) that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Please use the image button on the toolbar to add images to your code, rather than links to your own location. Images need to be placed into the SO imgur location so that they remain available for future use in your question.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little monstrous, but this might work:

```
=MIN(FILTER({
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet1!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet2!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet2!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet3!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet3!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet4!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet4!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet5!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet5!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet6!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet6!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet7!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet7!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet8!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet8!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet9!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet9!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet10!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet10!A2:F));
MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet11!A2:F),1,0),N(Sheet11!A2:F))},
{1,0,1,1,0,1}))
```

Comment: Had to adjust some stuff but that basically solved it. Thanks!